# appending a queryset to a list/tuple without evaluating it

Tags: django, django-queryset

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) a queryset gets evaluated when list() is called on it.

Is there a way to append a list/tuple with a queryset instead of model objects? Is list() called for every operation on lists/tuples?

e.g:

```
foo= Foo.objects.all()
bar = Bar.objects.filter(enabled=True)

my_list = []

my_list.append(foo) <-- evaluates
my_list.extend(foo) <-- evaluates

my_tuple = ()
my_tuple = my_tuple + (foo,) <-- evaluates

# so I'm getting
[<Foo: ModelDescription>,<Foo: ModelDescription>,<Bar: ModelDescription>]

#but I want
[<Queryset: Foo>, <Queryset:Bar>]
```

Comment: Are you certain that the first and third evaluate the query? They should not.

Comment: I think they do only evaluate in the active interpreter shell.

Comment: yep, they did. Putting the code in a view function solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is either no longer true or perhaps the way you were checking the type of the elements was inadvertently triggering the evaluation.

To summarize, you can use `append()` or `my_tuple = my_tuple + (foo,)`. If you try to just print these it will evaluate the QuerySet and output their contents but if you loop through these collections you can work with the actual `QuerySet`.

```
>>> a = Author.objects.filter()
>>> b = Book.objects.filter()
>>> type(a), type(b)
(<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>, <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>)
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(a)
>>> l.append(b)
>>> type(l[0]), type(l[1])
(<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>, <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>)
>>> for q in l:
...   print type(q)
... 
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
>>> my_tuple = ()
>>> my_tuple = my_tuple + (a,)
>>> type(my_tuple[0])
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
>>> len(l)
2
>>> len(my_tuple)
1
>>> print l
[[<Author: Author object>,  '...(remaining elements truncated)...'], [<Book: Book object>,]]
>>> len(my_tuple)
1
>>> print my_tuple
([<Author: Author object>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...'],)
>>> len(my_tuple)
1
>>>
```